# Entries appear to have vanished yet still show on the front end (sorta)?

Tags: ee1

I'm still using EE version 1.6.9 for one of my sites. On this page (http://www.logogala.com/designer/details/phil-heroux/) you can see a list of entries which are associated with this "designer" using the reverse_related_entries tag. There are three entries (global change leaders, red/blue barber shop, and blue atala) that still appear on this page yet when clicked, they take you to a 404 page. I've looked in my EE admin area and tried to find these entries and they are gone. No trace of these entries yet they still appear on this page using that reverse_related_entries tag. So... I'm at a loss; no idea what's going on or why these entries would have just vanished from the database yet still appear to show on this "designer profile page."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the entries were deleted but still exist in the Relationship Cache... You can [**clear the relationship cache**](http://ee1docs.com/cp/admin/utilities/clear_cached_data_files.html) at this location in the control panel"

> Control Panel Location:  Admin > Utilities > Clear Cached Data Files

Comment: Hmmm that definitely appears to be the issue as clearing the cache removed those entries from the front end. That said, I'm completely dumbfounded on why those entries were removed in the first place. I know for a fact that I didn't delete them and I'm the only admin of the site. But... at any rate, at least I know what the issue was. Thanks so much for the prompt support!

Comment: You're welcome... Take a look at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit-pro. Will log more CP info.